# Customizing the Web app deployment in Tomcat 7

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7

There are multiple web apps defined in the server.xml.

Depending on the instance, I want to chose which web apps needs to be deployed during the tomcat startup.

One obvious solution is to maintain different versions of server.xml for each instance type.

But I was wondering if there is a way to do it through code; some handlers that can be registered on the web app deployment lifecycle; and skip deploying a particular web app through the registered handler.

Does Tomcat[7 onwards] support such a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this issue by using hte tomcat manager to deploy the web apps. Registered a

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener

for tomcat startup event, and then used the tomcat manager to deploy the required web apps.